# Sync Apple Notes to OneNote online?

Tags: data-synchronization, notes.app, exchange, onenote

Question title pretty much says it all.  My wife just started working for a company that uses Office 365 online.  When she is using a work computer, she logs in to her Microsoft Exchange Mail, Calendar, and her OneNote account via a web browser.  When on her home computer, she can connect Apple Mail and Apple Calendar to her Exchange account.  Is there a way to sync her Apple Notes to her OneNote account?

*(I know that there is a Mac client for OneNote, by the way.  This question is about whether the native Notes app can sync to OneNote.)*

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is No.

Apple Notes and OneNoe can't be sync'd. You can export content from Notes and import it into OneNote, but they won't sync.